# Scrapy: how to use arguments for multiple search terms

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm playing around with scrapy and now I'm trying to search different keywords, passing arguments from the command line tool.
Basically, I would like to define a keyword and the crawler should search URLs that contains this keyword.
This is how my command line looks:

```
scrapy crawl myfirst -a nombre="Vermont"
```

And this is my crawler:

```
class myfirstSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myfirst'
    allowed_domains= ["leroymerlin.es"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.leroymerlin.es/decoracion-navidena/arboles-navidad?index=%s" % (page_number) for page_number in range(2)]    

    def __init__(self, nombre=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myfirstSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)    
        rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow= r'/fp/\*nombre*',), callback = 'parse_item'),)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        items = myfirstItem()

        product_name = response.css ('.titleTechniqueSheet::text').extract()

        items['product_name'] = product_name

        yield items
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work... 
Help is welcome, thanks!

I have found a way! It works for me:

```
class myfirstSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myfirst'
    allowed_domains= ["leroymerlin.es"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.leroymerlin.es/decoracion-navidena/arboles-navidad?index=%s" % (page_number) for page_number in range(2)]    

    def __init__(self, nombre=None, *args, **kwargs):

        self.rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow= nombre), callback = 'parse_item'),)
        super(myfirstSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        items = myfirstItem()

        product_name = response.css ('.titleTechniqueSheet::text').extract()

        items['product_name'] = product_name

        yield items
```

And the command:

```
scrapy crawl myfirst -a nombre="vermont"
```

Thank you to all of you!

Comment: _it doesn’t work_ ?

Comment: Try changing `rules` to `self.rules` and moving it *before* the `super` call.

Comment: Thanks for your comments... but it doesn't work anyway...

Comment: change `r'/fp/\*nombre*'` to `f'/fp/\*nombre*'`

Comment: @Unmair: Neither... I have realized that if I use 'def_ini' to define the 'start_urls' works but not in case of  'rules'... but I would like to define the 'rules' instead of 'start_urls'... So I'm stuck